# Is there any way to view several days of sysstat logs in kSar?

Tags: logs, sysstat

Is there any way to amalgamate days of sysstat logs, so one could view a whole week in kSar for example?

Currently I can only see individual days, loaded one at a time, or in separate windows.

Answer (score 1):

The sysstat logs themselves are in a binary format which doesn't allow concatenation. What you can do is to use `sadf` to convert them into e.g. CSV, which allows for concatenation.